# Knowledge Article - Experience Cloud Site - File Attachment Reporting

Tags: community, knowledge, lightning-knowledge, experience-builder-page

Currently, my company publishes knowledge articles on a customer portal (through the Experience Cloud Site). We built out a the knowledge object, which gives the name, author, description, and category of the tags. The related tab is where we attach the files. From the files we can toggle on the button for customer access.

We have noticed that sometimes a file was not attached to the article or the toggle "Customer Access" is not turned on. Resulting in the file not being attached when we go to view the article on the portal. I was wondering if there was a report that I could create that shows articles that do not have a file attached or if the toggle is not on. I was informed to use the Rollup Helper. I have never used the Rollup Helper, and after watching a few videos and demonstrations, I am still a little confused about how to build the rollup out.

Does anybody have guidance on this? TIA!

Comment: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZKjUAN/report-on-kb-articles-with-attachments